# Neural network to find a linear equation representing the data points

Tags: regression, neural-networks

Is it possible to use a neural network to do linear regression? Like can you use a neural network to output coefficients/weights (a1, a2, ..., an, and b) of a linear equation representing the features (x1, ..., xn)?

y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + .... + an * xn + b

Comment: The answer by Sycorax is correct. However, I wonder if the common implementations of neural networks allow for specifying zero hidden layers. Is there a reason why you would not use a linear regression directly?

Comment: Ah I see. I was merely curious if you could use neural networks. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neural network with zero hidden layers and an identity activation in the final layer is identically linear regression.

The predictions of this network are given by $$
\hat y = Xa + b
$$

which is the same as linear regression.